# Use queryset result as a parameter to a raw sql in Django

Tags: mysql, django

I have a queryset result that I need to retrieve, lets call it QSA, and also another queryset wich is obtained by Raw SQL, lets call this one QSB, but for the raw sql(QSB) I need only a field of QSA as a parameter, only one, but I don't want to make anoter query only just for that parameter.

I tried to send this as a parameter to QSB: `QSA.values('pk')` but it doesn't work, I obtained an empty result, and I tried to run the SQL query on Workbench and it works (I'm using MySql), so I think the problem is in the way that I send the parameter.

Comment: If you find a solution you can post an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Todor Thank you! I didn't notice about that haha... I always edit my question, from now I'm going to answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to make it work. I tried `%s` and `%(key)s` placeholders, and none of them worked with `QSA.values('pk')` as parameter, but later `%s` worked with `QSA.values_list('pk',flat=True)` and that's it, thats the way a queryset result can be send as parameter for a raw sql query in Django.